# Raising custom exceptions and output

Tags: python, exception

I have the following code from a tutorial:

```
class Ex(Exception):
    def __init__(self,msg):
        Exception.__init__(self,msg+msg)
        self.args=(msg,)


try:
    raise Ex('ex')
except Ex as e:
    print(e)
```

The question is what the output will be? I thought it would be `exex`. However, the output is `ex`. Now I am not understanding the construction. As far as I can see I can ignore the `self.args=(msg,)`. This does not matter. What I am not understanding is the line `Exception.__init__(self,msg+msg)`. I am not that used to exceptions.

Comment: If you think `self.args=(msg,)` does not matter, why is it there?

Comment: Your custom exception class looks like any other class which inherits from some other class. This is exactly what I would expect to see. What is it about that line that you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand what msg+msg does. So I call the __init__ from the superclass Exception and I hand over self, and msg+msg. Whoes does this do, handing over msg+msg? And what does the Exception.__init__(self,msg+msg) then do? When I remove self-args then msg+msg is the output. I do not understand this way.

Answer (score 2):

when calling `Exception.__init__(self,msg+msg)` the `msg+msg` (in this case `exex` is stored in the `args` attribute. by doing `self.args=(msg,)` afterwards, you are overwriting the previous assignment of the `args` attribute. if you want to print `exex` instead of just `ex`, simply remove `self.args=(msg,)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I do not understand the self.args. When I change it to self.test then exex is the output. What is this args?

Comment: please check out the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html): *"If `str()` is called on an instance of this class, the representation of the argument(s) to the instance are returned, or the empty string when there were no arguments."* `print()` calls `str()` on all it's arguments. all arguments passed into `Exception.__init__()` (except self) are stored in the `.args` attribute of the exception. when calling `str()` on an exception it will return all arguments stored in the `.args` attribute.

Comment: by doing `self.args=(msg,)` you are overwriting the `.args` attribute and the printed representation will be what you set the `.args` attribute to. when doing `self.test=(msg,)` you are not overwriting the `.args` attribute and therefore not changing what the printed output will be.